# TCP ,how to handle Server shutdown?

Tags: java, tcp

I am working on a TCP porject, and i have a problem how to handle the client side if the server go down. 
i tried to check with available if the server is still sending something.
But after i stop the server, it didnt print "Sever is down".

```
           InputStream   in = socket.getInputStream();


            BufferedInputStream i= new BufferedInputStream(in);
            obtainedObject = new ObjectInputStream(i);
                while (true) {
                            try {
                     if (i.available()==-1){
                    System.out.print("Server is down");
                                }
                      Object a = (Object) obtainedObject.readObject();

                          if (a.toString() != null) {
                             //bla bla
```

Comment: Could you post something that's at least *compilable* that also exhibits the behavior you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Throw the `available()` test away and just do the `readObject()`. It will throw `EOFException`when the server closes its end.